# How to remove key and value both from list of dictionary if value is nan/null/empty in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

How to remove key and value both from list of dictionary if value is nan/null/empty in python. I have tried to remove using below code but it is not getting removed.
is there anything wrong doing in the code.

We need to key and value pair if value is nan/null/empty.

**Code tried**

**1st method tried**

```
for key,value in address_dic.items():
    if value is 'nan':
        del address_dic[key]
```

**2nd method tried**

```
for key,value in dict(address_dic[address]).items():
    if value is 'nan':
        del address_dic[address][key]
```

**Input Data in address_dic**

```
{'source_id': 4402350, 'address': [{'address_type': 'Primary', 'address_line_1': '11815', 'address_line_2': nan}, {'address_type': 'work', 'address_line_1': nan, 'address_line_2': 123}]}
```

**Expected Output**

```
{'source_id': 4402350, 'address': [{'address_type': 'Primary', 'address_line_1': '11815'}, {'address_type': 'work', 'address_line_2': 123}]}
```

Comment: mutating dictionary when looping through it wont work. You have to create a new one and fill it with only with the data you want.

Comment: Agree with @yedpodtrzitk, You can't change the dictionary while iterating it. The only way is to create a new dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not modify a dictionary or list while iterating through its value. Create a new list of address which contains the value you need and replace the existing list with it.

**Input Data**

```py
address_dic = {
    "source_id": 4402350,
    "address": [
        {
            "address_type": "Primary",
            "address_line_1": "11815",
            "address_line_2": float("nan")
        },
        {
            "address_type": "work",
            "address_line_1": float("nan"),
            "address_line_2": 123
        }
    ]
}
```

**Main Logic**

```py
new_address = []

for addr in address_dic["address"]:
    # iterate through the dictionary and add the key-value pair
    # into a new dictionary if the value is not nan
    new_addr = {key: val for key, val in addr.items() if val == val} 
    new_address.append(new_addr)

address_dic["address"] = new_address
```

**Output**

```json
{
    "source_id": 4402350,
    "address": [
        {
            "address_type": "Primary",
            "address_line_1": "11815",
        },
        {
            "address_type": "work",
            "address_line_2": 123
        }
    ]
}
```

**One-Liner**

```py
address_dic["address"] = [{key: val for key, val in addr.items() if val == val} for addr in address_dic["address"]]
```

---

You can check if a value is nan in multiple ways:

```py
val = float("nan") # setting val as nan
```

**Pandas**

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.isna(val) # returns True if val is nan
```

**Numpy**

```py
import numpy as np
np.isnan(val) # returns True if val is nan
```

**Without External Library**

```py
val == val # returns False if val is nan
```

Comment: It is not removing 'nan' in final output

Comment: I am suspecting it is converting into some other values instead of 'nan'

Comment: If the 'nan' value in your case is of type float, the you have multiple options check for nan using: 1) Pandas: `pd.isna()` 2) Numpy:  `np.isnan()`

Comment: what does key:val play role here ?

Comment: Its a dictionary comprehension. Basically creating a dictionary while looping through set of key-value pairs. So if you break that line down, first I am looping through the key-value of each item in the `address` list using `for key, val in addr.items()`, then I am checking if the `val` is not a nan using `if val == val`. If the condition is satisfied, then I am creating the key-value pair in the new dictionary using `key: val`. Notice the line is enclosed with curly braces, meaning you are creating a dictionary. You can look up list/dictionary comprehension to understand the syntax better.

Comment: Thanks @Ashyam. How if val == val check for nan ?

Answer (score 0):

Like the below

```
data = {'source_id': 4402350,
        'address': [{'address_type': 'Primary', 'address_line_1': '11815', 'address_line_2': 'nan'},
                    {'address_type': 'work', 'address_line_1': 'nan', 'address_line_2': 123}]}

for entry in data['address']:
    for k in list(entry.keys()):
        if entry[k] == 'nan':
            del entry[k]
print(data)
```

output

```
{'source_id': 4402350, 'address': [{'address_type': 'Primary', 'address_line_1': '11815'}, {'address_type': 'work', 'address_line_2': 123}]}
```

Comment: No, he's not checking the key, he's checking `entry[key]`, which is correct.

Comment: @Naveen Did you copy/paste my code and run it? As far as I know it does exactly what you have asked for. Why dont you accept the answer?

Comment: It didn't work for me.. I don't have any issue to accept your answer if it is resolve the issue.

Comment: Did you copy/paste and run it? What is the output?

Comment: Yes i have copy/paste code and run it as well. I am getting output same as input.

Comment: what is the python version that you are using? Can you share the code that you have tested and does not work?

Comment: @balderman, In input we have value nan. I think you have taken 'nan' because of that code is nto working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236720/discussion-between-naveen-and-balderman).

Answer (score 0):

```
for addr in address_dic[address]:
    new_addr = {key: val for key, val in addr.items() if val == val}
    new_address.append(new_addr)
print(new_address)
address_dic["address"] = new_address
```

Comment: Can you add details about how the proposed code addresses the problem? Code-only answers are not very helpful, neither for the asked, nor others.

Answer (score -1):

There are two issues in this problem. First you have the problems that some `values` in your `dict` are lists of dictionaries. Second you cannot change the dictionary while for looping it, so you need to make copies.

Try:

```
d = {'source_id': 4402350, 'address': [{'address_type': 'Primary', 'address_line_1': '11815', 'address_line_2': 'nan'}, {'address_type': 'work', 'address_line_1': 'nan', 'address_line_2': 123}]}



for k,v in d.copy().items():
    if type(v) == list:
        for i, dd in enumerate(v):
            for k1,v1 in dd.copy().items():
                if v1 == 'nan':
                    dd.pop(k1)
                    v[i] = dd
    else:
        if v == 'nan':
            d.pop(k)

print(d)
```

Comment: we can't change the input. i can see in input data you have put np.nan.

Comment: changed, it was unclear to me if it's np.nan or 'nan' since you are missing the quotation on the first nan entry.

Comment: I have put the input data as it is as i get after printing address_dic["address"

Comment: are you sure that the first entry is just nan and the second entry is 'nan'?

Comment: we have value which is nan.. i don't know about first entry or second entry

Comment: that was typo in my question and sorry for that. We have value which is nan